# VBA: Unwanted overwriting rows

Tags: vba, excel

Already for some days, I'm searching the internet to find the correct code/help for my application.
The situation: If a certain product for a certain customer is done, column 9 give "Ready". When this happens, the whole row has to move to sheet 2 in a kind of 'history'-list and disappear out of the 'up-to-date'-list.

My code is the next:

Sub MoveDelete()

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For y = i To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(y, 9).Value = "Mag weg" Then
        Cells(y, 9).EntireRow.Cut Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 1)
        Cells(y, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

This code is working but gives other problems. Suppose today my range is 40 and 3 rows should be moved to the second worksheet, they are placed on row 40,39 and 38 (instead of 1,2,3 which would be better). But for example, tomorrow I add 5 rows in the up-to-date list and 4 old rows can be removed again, it will overwrite the previous ones (but I would like to have them on 4,5,6 and 7).

My goal is to have a list that I can update every day so the production line has a clear view of the workload and on the second page a list with all products/customerinformation that are done the last month.

I hope somebody can help me out here. If there are more questions, feel free to ask! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append the new moved rows to the end of what already exists in sheet2.

```
Sub MoveDelete()
    Dim i As Integer, y As Integer, j as Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Find first free row in sheet2
    j = Worksheets(2).cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    i = ActiveSheet.cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

    For y = i To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(y, 9).Value = "Mag weg" Then
            Rows(y).Copy Worksheets(2).Rows(j)
            Rows(y).EntireRow.Delete
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```